# How to roll back to previous Firestore Security Rules version

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, firebase-console

It is nice that Firebase security rules now [has version history](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/04/firestore-rules-management.html). However, I can't find out how I can actually roll back to a particular version, without having to manually copy the contents of a version that I want to roll back to and re-publish?

In Google App Engine, it's pretty easy to switch traffic to a particular version of my service and I was hoping for a similar feature...

[image: firebase console - rules]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying and pasting the rules is precisely what you will have to do, if you are using the Firebase console.

Your idea for easier rollback is good.  I suggest [filing the feature request with Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).

Note that you can also [manage security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/manage-deploy) using the Firebase CLI, so you can more easily use your source control to find old versions and redeploy them.

Comment: As can I see it's not possible to copy (select the text) rules with firefox ;) I had the same problem..

Answer (score 0):

the only solution is copying and pasting as @Doug said

but the issue is you cannot copy directly

so the solution is to compare between two versions, then you can copy from the previous version